# MS Word 2016 Bulk Accessibility

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ms-office, accessibility

all.

At work I'm tasked with training colleagues on how to create accessible content (Word, PDFs, spreadsheets) and also to retrofit some older attachments with a11y in mind.

As it stands I have about 4000 docs to make accessible by September:/ but progress feels really slow, especially as I also have to make accessible templates for other teams, train colleagues, attend meetings and do a few other tasks.

It's mostly just me doing this, I do get bits of help, but the folk on my team are also really busy with some other stuff that plays into the overall a11y project.

Presently I'm using MS Office 2016 on a Windows 10 machine. I'm trying to figure out ways of becoming more efficient, as sometimes it can take hours to remediate 1 lengthy document.

Are there any automation tools, VBA scripts, bulk tools or anything whatsover that can help?

I'm currently creating some macros that will address some common issues, but many documents are unique and I'm never going to be able to create macros for every error, especially alt text etc.

Obviously I'm up against time, budget constraints and a backlog longer than 1 person could possibly do in the time available. Still, it would be nice if I could speed the process up a bit and any time saving methods or tools I can develop or find would be a huge help. I can access some capital expenditure if the tool will definitely make a difference.

Cheers

Comment: I appreciate your pain bud but this will get closed as it is a question wanting **opinions** on choosing software / processes. Without seeing a selection of the documents this is impossible for us to offer any meaningful advice. I would normally point someone to another stack exchange but I am not sure where this fits. All I can say is instead of trying to fix every error, focus on the ones you CAN fix with macros in the time given, making 4000 documents 95% accessible is better than 400 documents that are 100% accessible. Also take impact into account, e.g. alt text > skipped heading levels

Comment: Thanks, Graham. I appreciate your taking the time to respond. I wasn't too sure there would be an alternative, as I have searched extensively, but I guess your response at least confirms I'm taking the most pragmatic approach I can.